# How can I use mongoose $lookup operator for lookup chaining and then grouping the result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Lets consider I have three pseudo collections like following

> **users**:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2c3dcf7961800e44dfc9"), "uid" : 1234, 
     "name" : "ashish", "email" : "info@gmail.com" }, 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2c51cf7961800e44dfca"), "uid" : 1235, 
     "name" : "swapnil", "email" : "info@femail.com" }
```

> **bank_details**:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2c9bcf7961800e44dfcb"), "uid" : 1234, "acc_no" : 1111 }, 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2cc9cf7961800e44dfcc"), "uid" : 1234, "acc_no" : 2222 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2cd7cf7961800e44dfcd"), "uid" : 1235, "acc_no" : 3333 }, 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2cdccf7961800e44dfce"), "uid" : 1235, "acc_no" : 4444 }
```

> **bank**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2d05cf7961800e44dfcf"), "acc_no" : 1111, "balance" : 100 }, 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2d10cf7961800e44dfd0"), "acc_no" : 2222, "balance" : 200 }, 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2d19cf7961800e44dfd1"), "acc_no" : 3333, "balance" : 300 }, 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2d21cf7961800e44dfd2"), "acc_no" : 4444, "balance" : 400 }
```

> **I wanna have output as following**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2c3dcf7961800e44dfc9"), "uid" : "1234", 
  "name" : "ashish", "email" : "info@gmail.com" ,
bank_details: [{
  acc_no:'1111',
  balance:'100'
},{
  acc_no:'2222',
  balance:'200'
}]}
```

for each profile of user, I'm sure this can be done using `$lookup` and `$group` operator but I could never achieve it, I have tried to do this using several ways. Can anybody please write a sample query for the required result.

I'm trying to write the query using mongoose in NodeJs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using two lookups and grouping. Check out the following query:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([{
  $lookup:
    {
      from: "bank_details",
      localField: "uid",
      foreignField: "uid",
      as: "bank_details"
    }
},
{   $unwind:{ path: "$bank_details", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
{
    $lookup:{
        from: "bank", 
        localField: "bank_details.acc_no", 
        foreignField: "acc_no",
        as: "banks"
    }
},
{ $unwind: { path: "$banks", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        uid: {$first: "$uid"},
        name: {$first: "$name"},
        email: {$first: "$email"},
        bank_details: {$push: {acc_no: "$banks.acc_no", balance: "$banks.balance"}}
        }
    },
{ 
   "$project": {
      uid: 1,
      name: 1,
      email: 1,
      bank_details: { "$setDifference": [ "$bank_details", [{}, null] ] }
   }
}
])
```

Results:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2c51cf7961800e44dfca"),
"uid" : 1235.0,
"name" : "swapnil",
"email" : "info@femail.com",
"bank_details" : [ 
    {
        "acc_no" : 3333.0,
        "balance" : 300.0
    }, 
    {
        "acc_no" : 4444.0,
        "balance" : 400.0
    }
]
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2c3dcf7961800e44dfc9"),
"uid" : 1234.0,
"name" : "ashish",
"email" : "info@gmail.com",
"bank_details" : [ 
    {
        "acc_no" : 1111.0,
        "balance" : 100.0
    }, 
    {
        "acc_no" : 2222.0,
        "balance" : 200.0
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @Volodymyr, it's working as expected. But there is one small problem, I'm losing the information of the user who has no entry in the bank_details collection. Can I not retain the information of such users? I mean there should be blank array for those users having no entry in bank_details collection but other details of the users like email should be projected.

Comment: Use `{ $unwind: { path: "$bank_details", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }` to keep empty and null arrays.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to lose the users that have no `bank_details` you have to add a `$project` before you unwind. By "$unwind" you flatten the `bank_details` array and the documents that have an empty array, disappear after since there is nothing to unwind. So you can check your `bank_detail`s array if it's empty and add zero values to the fields:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: "bank_details",
            localField: "uid",
            foreignField: "uid",
            as: "bank_details"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            uid: "$uid",
            name: "$name",
            email: "$email",
            bank_details: {
                $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$bank_details", []]
                    },
                    [{
                        _id: 0,
                        uid: {
                            $literal: NumberInt(0)
                        },
                        acc_no: {
                            $literal: NumberInt(0)
                        }
                    }], '$bank_details'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$bank_details"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "bank",
            localField: "bank_details.acc_no",
            foreignField: "acc_no",
            as: "banks"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            uid: "$uid",
            name: "$name",
            email: "$email",
            bank_details: "$bank_details",
            banks: {
                $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$banks", []]
                    },
                    [{
                        _id: 0,
                        acc_no: {
                            $literal: NumberInt(0)
                        },
                        balance: {
                            $literal: NumberInt(0)
                        }
                    }], '$banks'
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    {
        $unwind: "$banks"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            uid: {
                $first: "$uid"
            },
            name: {
                $first: "$name"
            },
            email: {
                $first: "$email"
            },
            bank_details: {
                $push: {
                    acc_no: "$banks.acc_no",
                    balance: "$banks.balance"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Here the results of the query:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a83a53b3899dec93be178"),
    "uid" : 1239,
    "name" : "emil",
    "email" : "emil@femail.com",
    "bank_details" : [ 
        {
            "acc_no" : 0.0,
            "balance" : 0.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2c51cf7961800e44dfca"),
    "uid" : 1235,
    "name" : "swapnil",
    "email" : "info@femail.com",
    "bank_details" : [ 
        {
            "acc_no" : 3333,
            "balance" : 300
        }, 
        {
            "acc_no" : 4444,
            "balance" : 400
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a2c3dcf7961800e44dfc9"),
    "uid" : 1234,
    "name" : "ashish",
    "email" : "info@gmail.com",
    "bank_details" : [ 
        {
            "acc_no" : 1111,
            "balance" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "acc_no" : 2222,
            "balance" : 200
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but your query is giving me an error message: 'The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion'

Comment: @PointNetworks that is probably a mongoose specific error, cause I don't get it when executing directly in MongoDB. Anyway I updated the answer by removing the `_id` field from the `bank_details` in the `$project` pipeline. So try it out again.

Comment: No @Alex it still didn't work. I'm checking the reason but not understanding the error

Comment: I tried executing your query directly on mongo console but still, it didn't work. And gave me an exactly same error. quite confused :O

Comment: ah okay, maybe it was due to `"_id": 1` in the `$project` pipeline, cause it gets confused with the other _id's. Anyway, I changed it to `"_id": "$_id"`. This must work now

Comment: thanks Alex for your help but no still it didn't work and giving me the same error

Comment: @PointNetworks not sure why my mongo doesn't complain. Maybe we have different mongodb versions. I checked out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153168/mongodb-aggregation-with-project-to-conditionally-exclude-a-field)  it could be due to the other fields that where set to 0 in the `$project` pipeline, E.g `acc_no: 0`. I changed it now to take it as a literal and also an integer. Try it out one more time, I'm really sorry if it doesn't work. I tried...

Comment: no problem Alex. Well your new code didn't work either. But yeah I found one workaround that if I make the array empty which contains those Littrel keywords. It starts working but consequently I also lose the grouping of those users and also I don't get those users who are not having entry into bank_details. Which means source of the problem is in that array. Anyway thanks again

Comment: Updated answer of @Volodymyr to this question worked perfectly.